# Measure python asyncio task pressure

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have some python code that spins up quite a few asyncio tasks. I would like to know at which point I have spun up to many.

Concretely, this means that I would like to measure how many tasks are currently waiting in a queue to be run (i.e., these would be the tasks that would like to have some cpu time, but can't because another task is occupying it).

I would also like to know what the average waiting time of a task is.

Comment: How long is the queue: [`asyncio.all_tasks()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.all_tasks) Average wait time would likely be done best by using `time.time()` or the [`cprofile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) library possibly.

Comment: `asyncio.all_tasks()` measures the total amount of tasks in the loop. I would like to know how many tasks are runnable at a certain point in time (i.e. they are not waiting for some io or a different task to finish).

Comment: If that functionality exists beyond inspecting `Task.get_stack()` for each of `asyncio.all_tasks()`, I cannot find it. I suppose you could simply look at cpu time / io time etc using `psutil`